# Android LocationListener vs NMEAlistener

Tags: android

I am playing around with android's LocationManager and I thought it was interesting that there are two interfaces to get GPS data. I am referring to a LocationListener or a NMEAlistener.

I am just interested on pros/cons of them both. Does the locationListener just save me the hassle of parsing of NMEA data? am I losing accuracy or performance? or something that I am not seeing...

I do not see many tutorials or examples using the NMEA listener but I have used NMEA data from other GPS sources and found things went smoothly.

Thanks

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the locationListener just save me the hassle of parsing of NMEA data?

Not really, the raw GPS data from the chipset is *converted* into  NMEA *and* Location

> I losing accuracy or performance?

No, if you want additional GPS data that Location object does not provide, use the NMEA listener, otherwise stick the LocationListener.

Answer (score -2):

NMEA listener is for listening to NMEA 0183 sentences from GPS sources.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183